# IPhone - ViewSwitch Problem

Tags: iphone, view, switch-statement

HI everybody, I've got a problem with the view-switch. When first switching into the landscapeview everything seems to be ok, but switching back into the portraitview my view is scaled in the wrong way.

so the left picture shows how it should look like (and how it looks before the switch),
and the right one shows how it actually looks after the switch:

http://img43.imageshack.us/gal.php?g=bild2mu.png

has anybody an idea what I can do to fix it, thx a lot,
regard Mirrow

Answer (score 0):

How do you make frame changing during rotation? just set `autoresizingMask` property of your table to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and it should be fine.